# Access vba code not exporting to EXCEL "Too few parameters. Expected 1."

Tags: vba, ms-access, export-to-excel

I have some code I previous got from one of my other Access Databases, which works fine. It intended purpose was to copy the results that were put into a make table into a blank excel sheet then format the columns.

I however copied the code and tweaked it a little. What I am trying to do with the copied code is still export my results into a blank excel sheet, however, this time I am not coping from a make table but from a select query. I am not sure if it is possible but there is no other way for me to make this into a make table, it has to be an select query. Is there any way someone can help? The code I have now is:

```
Option Compare Database
Public Function Export_EXCEL()


Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim Response As Integer
Dim strSQL As String
Dim Query1 As String
Dim LTotal As String
  Dim Excel_App As Excel.Application 'Creates Blank Excel File
  Dim strTable As String ' Table in access
    Dim queryDelete As String 'SQL to delete records in local table
    Dim strAssigned As DAO.Recordset

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
strTable = "Select * From cso_sup_SETUP" 'Access Query I am trying to copy

    Set Excel_App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set dbs = CurrentDb
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strTable)

    Excel_App.Visible = True

Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
  Set wkb = Excel_App.Workbooks.Add

Dim rg As Excel.Range
Dim i As Long
' Add the headings
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
Next i

Set rg = wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1)
rg.CopyFromRecordset rs

' make pretty
rg.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit


Set rs = Nothing
Set wkb = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing

End Function
```

This is the modified code below:

```
Option Compare Database
Public Function Export_EXCEL()


Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim Response As Integer
Dim strSQL As String
Dim Query1 As String
Dim LTotal As String
  Dim Excel_App As Excel.Application 'Creates Blank Excel File
  Dim strTable As String ' Table in access
   Dim queryDelete As String 'SQL to delete records in local table
   Dim strAssigned As DAO.Recordset

 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
 Dim db As DAO.Database
 Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
 Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

 '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 strTable = "Select * From cso_sup_SETUP" 'Access Query I am trying to copy

Set Excel_App = New Excel.Application
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
 '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Set rs = QuerDef.OpenRecordset(strTable)

Excel_App.Visible = True

Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
  Set wkb = Excel_App.Workbooks.Add

Dim rg As Excel.Range
Dim i As Long
 ' Add the headings
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
   wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
 Next i

Set rg = wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1)
rg.CopyFromRecordset rs

' make pretty
rg.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit


 Set rs = Nothing
 Set wkb = Nothing
 Set dbs = Nothing

 End Function
```

Comment: Upon which line does that error pop?

Comment: @JNevill The error is appearing on this line: "Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strTable)"

Comment: Unrelated. This line: `Set Excel_App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` would make more sense as `Set Excel_App = New Excel.Application` so you don't have a mix of early and late binding.

Comment: Same error is occurring on the same line of code?

Comment: Try switch that line over to `Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strTable, dbOpenDynaset)`.

Comment: I thought that would work but I am getting the same error

Comment: HansUp it is a query. A select query

Comment: HansUp, yes I have Forms!MyForm! is being used under the cso_sup_SETUP select query. I added your suggestion about QuerDef.OpenRecordset and I am however getting a new error on this line of code stating "Object Required"?

Comment: "Set rs = QuerDef.OpenRecordset(strTable)" This line of code is where the new error is at stating "Object Required"

Answer (score 1):

This error has one of two causes:

*Cause 1* - You have specified a field name in query `cso_sup_SETUP` that does not exist in the underlying table. In this case, Access treats the non-existent field as a "parameter", and throws a `Too few parameters` error if you try to open it in code.

*Cause 2* - You have defined a Parameter in query `cso_sup_SETUP`, but have not supplied a value in code.

Fixes:

*Fix 1* - Remove the non-existent field, or correct the spelling (look for `Expr1`)

*Fix 2* - Supply a parameter value in code per HansUp's suggestion.

Comment: Spelling is dead on point with the query name lol.. I tried fix 2 but getting a new error "object required" I am still fumbling around with vba so still learning things as it approaches. & this one is new to me

Comment: Well, if you have defined a parameter, it is easy to see. Just open the query in SQL view, and if you see a `PARAMETERS` statement at the top, you have parameters. If not, you can safely ignore cause 2.

Answer (score 1):

You have an Access `QueryDef` (a saved query) named *"cso_sup_SETUP"*.  That query references a control on a form ... something like `Forms!MyForm!MyTextbox`. 
 When you open that query in the Access query designer, it can retrieve the text box value the query needs.  However when you attempt to use the query with the DAO `OpenRecordset` method, it is unable to retrieve the text box value and treats `Forms!MyForm!MyTextbox` as a parameter for which you have not supplied a value.

You can load your `Recordset` by setting an object variable to the `QueryDef` and then supplying the form control's value as a `Parameter` before calling the `QueryDef.OpenRecordset` method.

Note your problem does not actually have anything to do with Excel --- it's a purely Access problem.  So here is Access VBA code which should give you the `Recordset` I think you need.  Suggest you create a new procedure in your code module to test this.  Once you have it working, either add the Excel bits from the original procedure or adapt the original to use this.

Also strongly suggest you add `Option Explicit` to your module's *Declarations* section.  Put it on a new line immediately below `Option Compare Database`

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("cso_sup_SETUP")
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm.value = Eval(prm.Name)
Next
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
```