# How do I get OpenRecordSet in VBA to open a query rather than a table?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office

I am attempting to add entries to a table by pulling information from various sources. I have the code set up to execute these steps only if a procedure fails, and while it will open the first two tables just fine it gives me a "Too few parameters" error when I try to call a built-in query (one I have set up in Access.)

I've tried to open a Querydef and tried putting it in as an SQL statement, but neither has worked. I don't want to have to dump it into another temporary table and read from that, but it might come to that. Here's the section of code I have for this:

```
'Only add to the Details table if the audit failed.
If auditMatch = False Then
   Set tempRs = db.OpenRecordset("tempAudit")
   Set auditRefRs = db.OpenRecordset("auditLogDetails")
   'Set locationRs = db.OpenRecordset("qryLocationCheck")
```

Comment: ```SELECT DISTINCT tblWarehouse.PartNumber AS [Part Number], tblWarehouse.Location AS Location
FROM tblWarehouse
WHERE (((tblWarehouse.Location)=[Forms]![frmAudit]![tbxLocationAudit]));```

And for reference, the form mentioned in the query is open when this query is ran.

Comment: `[Forms]![frmAudit]![tbxLocationAudit]` is the problem.  OpenRecordset can't resolve it and treats it as a regurlar parameter instead.

Comment: Look into `QueryDef.OpenRecordset` instead of `Database.OpenRecordset` and give it the parameter value it wants.  For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60801595/77335).

Comment: @P.Fowler, it won't matter if form is open when calling query like this in VBA to open a recordset - still won't be able to resolve the form reference. I don't use dynamic parameters in query object if I can avoid it. Use a SELECT statement in VBA and provide filter criteria there instead of just referencing table or query name. Why using VBA to create records and not data entry on form?

Comment: using the QueryDef object is the right approach for running queries with parameters with vba.  The other choice is pasting your parameters into long strings of sql. Unfortunately, I find it is always hard to find a good guide to using QueryDefs.  here was the best I found after 15 minutes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568461/is-it-possible-to-pass-parameters-programmatically-in-a-microsoft-access-update

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to pass parameters programmatically in a Microsoft Access update query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568461/is-it-possible-to-pass-parameters-programmatically-in-a-microsoft-access-update)

Comment: Hans's suggestion helped. Utilized the Parameter assignments in the code he shows in his link. (Can't upvote it, unfortunately.)